# Java compareTo string based on whole value ( not lexicographically)

Tags: android, string, unicode

The default String compareTo() function compares lexicographically i.e character by character.

E.g. String "3222368" is lesser than "9876135" because 3 < 9.

But i want to compare the whole value based on [how swift does it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string). The sections of importance -

> **Comparing Strings Using Operators**
>
> Comparing strings using the equal-to
> operator (==) or a relational operator (like < and >=) is always
> performed using the Unicode canonical representation, so that
> different representations of a string compare as being equal.

AND

> **static func <=(String, String)**
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the value of the first
> argument is less than or equal to that of the second argument

How can i do this in Java ?

I tried looking up **java.text.Collator**
and tried this -

```
Collator myDefaultCollator = Collator.getInstance();
return myDefaultCollator.compare(string1, string2);
```

and it's not working.

Could you help me out ?

UPDATE:
I'm looking to sort the strings using the compareTo() method.

Comment: You should just call `Objects.equals()`, like this: `Objects.equals("test", new String("test"))`  --> true, 
`Objects.equals(null, "test")` --> false

Comment: I'm looking to sort using the compareTo() method and not looking for equals().